# Graph representation is C algorithm

Tags: c, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Im trying to implement a 'C' and 'SDL' (For the representation) algorithm to solve "Unblock Me" puzzle game.
For who never heard about the puzzle : 
It's a board game where you have to move the Red Shape (Most of the time it's a box) out of the grid by moving other shapes of different dimensions.

[Board exemple](https://prnt.sc/52ymia)

[Grid representation](https://prnt.sc/52yn9w)

I'm trying to solve the grid using both DFS (Depth First Search), and BFS (Breadth First Search), I do understand the algorithms.

I'm not looking for a code solution, I'm just looking for a documentation or someone who can explain me how can i use my grid representation with DFS or BFS, which i couldn't answer after searching on *stackoverflow* and similar websites.

I spent the last two days making research about BFS and DFS but i still can't answer some questions considering the previous given grid representation:

**What are the nodes ?**

**What are the links ?**

**What's gonna be the adjacency matrix?**

**I appreciate any documentation link.**

Some of documentation links which i did already read :
[Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: Post required  information here to add clarity to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each particular search problem may admit convenient specialised representations. But in theoretical terms, and that  may be a good starting point, you can think of a "node" as a "board configuration", and an "edge connecting c1 to c2" as a "move transforming configuration c1 into c2".